# odoo- add custom fields in advaced search?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

i'm trying to add product description to purchase advanced search menu

```
class purchase_order_line(osv.osv):
_inherit = 'purchase.order.line'
_columns =  {
    'name':fields.text(string='Description')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not clear for me. But i noticed an error in your code. You missed an equal sign after _columns. Try below code.

```
 class purchase_order_line(osv.osv):
 _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'
 _columns =  {
 'name':fields.text(string='Description')
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to search by product discription, its work by searching by order line :)

thanks